# Geofire query at once instead of 1 by 1

Tags: javascript, firebase, geofire

My snippet code below, it first query `geo keys` then look up related data with `value` event. But there is a problem, keys are return in 1 by 1 so my list view also display in row by row. How can I query `geo keys` in ONCE?

```
geoQuery.on('ready', () => {
  geoQuery.cancel()
})

geoQuery.on("key_entered", (key, location, distance) => {
  postsRef.child(key).once('value', (snapshot) => {
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_NEARBY_SUCCESS,
      response: normalize(snapshot.val(), schema.post)
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected behavior: the `key_entered` event is fired once for every key that is inside the range initially, and then once for every key as it enters the range.

If you want to perform some update after the initial data has loaded, e.g. delay updating the screen, you can listen for the `ready` event. From the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#geoqueryoneventtype-callback):

> `ready` fires once when this query's initial state has been loaded from the server. The `ready` event will fire after all other events associated with the loaded data have been triggered.

Comment: I can't figure out what i can do to delay screen update to look smooth in `ready` event?

Comment: The `ready` event fires after a batch of data has been loaded. So if you don't send any updates to the UI until you get the `ready` event, you can delay updating your screen until the initial data has loaded.

Comment: Got it. Thank you